# SFTP won't launch when using custom script through ForceCommand on Win32 SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp

I've written a script to send an email alert when a user logs in via SSH.  It is triggered through ForceCommand.  This works fine when opening terminal windows but SFTP won't work (Bitvise log says "SFTP channel opened" but no SFTP window comes up).  Am I missing something in the script file

From sshd_config:

```
#Run command at login
ForceCommand c:\ProgramData\ssh\login.bat
```

Here is script (login.bat)

```
@echo off

REM For colored text; see :colorEcho below
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

ipconfig /all
echo:
REM Get current date and time
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
call :colorEcho a0 "User %LOGNAME% connected to %COMPUTERNAME% from %SSH_CONNECTION% at %mydate%_%mytime%"
REM Send alert that user has connected.
c:\BatchFiles\EmailMessage\EmailMessage.exe -s "New Connection to %COMPUTERNAME%" -b "User %LOGNAME% connected to %COMPUTERNAME% from %SSH_CONNECTION% at %mydate%_%mytime%"
echo:
echo:

REM Send original command from SSH so shell will start
cmd %SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND%

REM This provides for colored text
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work any better if you remove the "colorEcho" contraption and just directly include the raw ESC sequences in the script?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Tried a login.bat with just "cmd %SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND%"; ran into the same issue (shell worked fine but got same error with SFTP as above).  Thanks for your reply!